# Giving directory access to only certain users?

Tags: linux, unix

I currently have the following directory:

```
drwxrwsr-x   4 user1 Group1 4.0K Apr 18 18:29 foo
```

Under `Group1` there are 20 users. I want to give `user2` and `user3` who belong to `Group1` access to directory `foo` and restrict access to this directory to everyone else. Can someone please tell me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new group, add `user2` and `user3` to that group. Change the group ownership of the directory to the new group.

Comment: May be a dumb question but what if I don't have the ability to execute `groupadd`? My server complains: `groupadd: unable to lock group file`

Comment: Are you running it as `root`? If all else fails, `strace` it and see exactly what operation is failing.

Comment: I don't have `root` privileges on the server so I guess that is the problem I am running into. Running `strace` tells me that the permission was denied while accessing `/etc/.pwd.lock` file.

Comment: Then you'll either have to ask the root user to create the group for you or use [access control lists](http://linux.die.net/man/1/setfacl) if your system supports them. If your need is legitimate, I'd suggest asking the system administrator how you should meet it.

Comment: +1 Thank you. I just emailed my admin. Hopefully he will get back soon. Thanks for your help.